# How to add a few lines of code to an existing file in my NuGet package?

Tags: nuget

I have added a few lines of code into the `Startup.cs` file. How can I include only that change in the NuGet package? I certainly don't want to include the whole `Startup.cs`, for, it will perform an overwrite.

Answer (score 3):

Right now NuGet does not support this scenario, without overwriting the existing startup.cs file.

NuGet does support transforming XML files with syntax of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx though.

Please open an issue on nuget.codeplex.com as a feature request if this does not solve your need.