# How to transform/increment code on a .cs file on a Nuget package

Tags: package, nuget, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm creating a Nuget Package for an ASP.NET MVC5 Application, and i want to increment a simple line of code to an already existent file in my project, which is the /App_Start/BundleConfig.cs.

I want to add this line to it:

```c#
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/ajaxhelper").Include("~/Scripts/jquery.ajaxhelper.js"));
```

I have created this file in my package, with the name BundleConfig.cs.pp, which successful rename the namespace to it's original project name:

```c#
namespace $rootnamespace$
{
    public class BundleConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/ajaxhelper").Include("~/Scripts/jquery.ajaxhelper.js"));
        }
    }
}
```

But it replaces the whole file with all the existent bundles in it, it doesn't increment with the line i want it to. I've tried change the file to BundleConfig.cs.transform and it throws a exception.

Is it possible to increment the code on the file i want or do i have to create a new Bundle.cs file just to add my ajaxhelper bundle?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add a few lines of code to an existing file in my NuGet package?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20250628/how-to-add-a-few-lines-of-code-to-an-existing-file-in-my-nuget-package)

Comment: Have you tried writing a custom class that extends RegisterBundles and adds your bundle to the BundleCollection, then preprossess that class when the package is installed? your package would need a reference to the WebActivator library. See here: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/UpdatingAndPublishingANuGetPackagePlusMakingNuGetPackagesSmarterAndAvoidingSourceEditsWithWebActivator.aspx